# Snowpark python date format

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowpark, I have a date column in the format of `%Y-%m-%d`. I want to create another column (a version of it) in the form of `%Y-%m`. In Pandas this would have been:

```
df['start_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date']).dt.to_period('M')
```

How to do this in Snowpark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

- `try_to_date` - input/column to date data type(if already date it could be skipped
- `to_varchar` - to YYYY-MM string format

Code:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col, sql_expr

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    df = session.create_dataframe(["2023-04-05", "2023-05-02"], schema=["start_date"])
    
    df = df.select(col("start_date"), \
                   sql_expr("to_varchar(try_to_date(start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM')") \
                   .as_("start_month"))
    return df
```

Output:

| START_DATE | START_MONTH |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-05 | 2023-04 |
| 2023-05-02 | 2023-05 |

---

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
import datetime
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col, sql_expr

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    df = session.create_dataframe([datetime.date(2023,4,5), datetime.date(2023,5,2)], schema=["start_date"])
    
    df = df.select(col("start_date"), \
                   sql_expr("to_varchar(start_date, 'YYYY-MM')").as_("start_month"))
    return df
```